# Indesign data merge and facing pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I know that my question is could already be asked, but I can't find a clear answer.

I'm new to Indesign (i'm coming from webdesign), and I have to create a catalog. Each page contains the photo of a product and the description. To generate my indesign file, i've used data merging, and it works ok, in a way.

The only thing I'm not able to do, it's to have:

- on the left page: the photo on left side and text on the right side
- on the right page: the photo on the right side and text on left.

**It is possible without paying for plugin like easy catalog?
Should I use XML ? What's the easiest way to do this?**

I've tried to check/uncheck the "facing page" option, before and after data merging, but the pages are always the same.

Note : I'm using Indesign CS3, perhaps a more recent version has this possibility?

Thanks,
PS: sorry for my english...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InDesign's data merge feature is - like much Adobe software - old, rusty and in desperate need of an update that will probably never come. Often, it's **easier to solve data merge problems in the spreadsheet than in InDesign**.

I'd deal with this one by changing the spreadsheet from being like this:

```
----------------------
| @Image  | Text     |
----------------------
| Image 1 | Text 1   |
| Image 2 | Text 2   |
| Image 3 | Text 3   |
| Image 4 | Text 4   |
| Image 5 | Text 5   |
| Image 6 | Text 6   |
| ...     | ...      |
```

...to this:

```
-------------------------------------------
| @Image-L| Text-L   | @Image-R| Text-R   |
-------------------------------------------
| Image 1 | Text 1   | Image 2 | Text 2   |
| Image 3 | Text 3   | Image 4 | Text 4   |
| Image 5 | Text 5   | Image 6 | Text 6   |
| ...     | ...      | ...     | ...      |
```

Then, you can have a 2-page, 1-spread template with the left side arranged how you want using `<<@Image-L>>` and `<<Text-L>>` placeholders, and the right side arranged how you want using `<<@Image-R>>` and `<<Text-R>>` placeholders.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is a good option and makes the job. I hoped there was a solution to do this directly in Indesign but as you say Adobe software is desesperatly old.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at this, it tells you exactly how to do it, 
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/instant-indesign/automating-a-catalog-with-data-merge/

Comment: Hello chelsian, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer! Could you please give a short version of the relevant content at the link you gave? That way, your answer is still valuable in case the link breaks at a later time. Thanks!